# Firefox tabs: are they valid drag-n-drop entities?

Tags: firefox, drag-and-drop, draggable

Tried to d&d FF tab into notepad window. Above it, the cursor changed, showing that this can't be dropped here. Same behavior in Chrome.

Which Windows tools may be used to determine type of object prepared for D&D (if the window can/can not accept such object), when d&d-mode cursor is passed to the window?

Comment: Gah. with those bounties I'll never get 400 rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-tips-tricks/drag-drop-tabs-firefox-google-chrome-7256.html - they can be accepted in Chrome, receiving the URL. No plugins involved.